# Data adapter fill dataset error ,SQL connection error

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, xml, dataset

I am trying to make a SQL query and save the result in an XML file but I get the error as thepicture I attached here
INVALID COLUMN!
this query works fine in SQL server but not here

```
namespace xxxxxxxxxxxx
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        string vinValue;
        string operationValue;
        string serviceValue;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void FrameLoad_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btnGo_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter adapter;

        string sql = String.Format("SELECT FGACJD_Vin_Ecu.Vin,FGACJD_Vin_Ecu.NHard,"+
            "FGACJD_Vin_Ecu.NVerHard,FGACJD_Vin_Ecu.NSoft,FGACJD_Vin_Ecu.NVerSoft,"+
            "InfoProg_wiTECH_Global.NHard,InfoProg_wiTECH_Global.NVerHard,"+
            "InfoProg_wiTECH_Global.NSoft,InfoProg_wiTECH_Global.NSoftNew,"+
            "InfoProg_wiTECH_Global.NVerSoft,InfoProg_wiTECH_Global.NomeFile,"+
            "InfoProg_wiTECH_Associa.KeyJoined,InfoProg_wiTECH_Associa.MakeID,"+
            "InfoProg_wiTECH_Associa.ModelID,InfoProg_wiTECH_Associa.Model_Type "+
            "FROM FGACJD_Vin_Ecu, InfoProg_wiTECH_Global,InfoProg_wiTECH_Associa "+
            "WHERE [FGACJD_Vin_Ecu.Vin]='{0}'"+
            " AND InfoProg_wiTECH_Associa.KeyJoined = InfoProg_wiTECH_Global.NomeFile"+
            " AND FGACJD_Vin_Ecu.NHard=InfoProg_wiTECH_Global.NHard"+
            " AND InfoProg_wiTECH_Global.NVerHard like '%'+FGACJD_Vin_Ecu.NVerHard "+
            "FOR XML PATH('flash'), ROOT ('FlashList ')", vinValue);


        //TextOutput.Text = sql;
        string connectionString = "user id=xxx;password=xxx;"+
                        "server=localhost;" +
                        "Trusted_Connection=yes;" +
                        "database=xxx; " +
                        "connection timeout=30";

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            string err = "Database error contact administrator";
            MessageBox.Show(err, "Error!");
        }

        try
        {

            adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
            adapter.Fill(ds);
            conn.Close();
            ds.WriteXml("Product.xml");
            MessageBox.Show("Done");
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
   }

    private void TextInput_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        vinValue = TextInput.Text;
    }

    private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var comboBox = sender as ComboBox;
        serviceValue = comboBox.SelectedItem as string;
        this.Title = "Selected: " + serviceValue;
    }

    private void ComboBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> data = new List<string>();
        data.Add("getFlashListByVIN");
        var comboBox = sender as ComboBox;
        comboBox.ItemsSource = data;
        comboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }

    private void Operation_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> data = new List<string>();
        data.Add("MOC");
        var comboBox = sender as ComboBox;
        comboBox.ItemsSource = data;
        comboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }

    private void Operation_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var comboBox = sender as ComboBox;
        operationValue = comboBox.SelectedItem as string;
        this.Title = "Selected: " + operationValue;
    }
}
```

}

I get this error

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid column name
>   'FGACJD_Vin_Ecu.Vin'.    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds,
>   RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean
>   async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader
>   ds)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task,
>   Boolean asyncWrite)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, String method)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior)    at
>   System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior)    at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet
>   dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords,
>   String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)    at
>   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, Int32
>   startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command,
>   CommandBehavior behavior)    at
>   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet)    at
>   FlashListByVinLadan.MainWindow.btnGo_Click(Object sender,
>   RoutedEventArgs e) in
>   c:\Users\Finsoft\Desktop\test\FlashListByVinLadan\FlashListByVinLadan\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line
>   80 ClientConnectionId:3653b64e-bb82-41cb-8fc8-4d92fbaa3c3e Error
>   Number:207,State:1,Class:16

Comment: Invalid column name 'FGACJD_Vin_Ecu.Vin', are you sure everything matches with your database?

Comment: Using `String.Format` does not prevent you from sql-injection. Instead use sql-parameters.

Comment: I would also use a [verbatim string literal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(v=vs.71).aspx), then you can use the same query that works in SSMS. You just need to prepend `@`, then you can remove all those `"+
            "` even with multiple lines.

Comment: use parameters and change `[FGACJD_Vin_Ecu.Vin]`into `[FGACJD_Vin_Ecu].[Vin]`

Comment: sql is wrong ? parameter ?

Answer (score 1):

sql is wrong

```
WHERE FGACJD_Vin_Ecu.Vin='{0}'
```